# Text To Columns isn't working in my vba script

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vba7

I am trying to get my Text To Columns to work in my VBA script, but it's not working for me.
I understand how it works in excel and even used the macro record to get it working, but when adding it to my script nothing happens. I even looked at online forums. What I'm doing is extracting data from one workbook to the other and the data that I am getting needs to be converted to Text To Columns once the data is transferred to the other workbook.

I have two separate Sub functions that I used below: Neither of them worked. One of them is from the macro record and the other I found online.

Code from Macro Record below:

```
Sub TextToCol()

    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("D3"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=True, Other:=False, OtherChar _
        :="" & Chr(10) & "", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1)), _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End Sub
```

Code from online forum below:

```
Sub TextToCol()    
    Selection.Range("D3:D8").TextToColumns _
    DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
    ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, _
    Space:=True
End Sub
```

The code below is what I am using to connect to source workbook:

```
'Save Above Created New Workbook
sWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\username\Desktop\fileName\Test.xlsx"
FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your File & Import Range", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls*")
Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
```

Below is the code to send data to the destination workbook:

```
Workbooks("Test.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & counter).value = dataThatWasExtracted
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens when you run your code?

Comment: When I run it the form is the same. It doesn't convert to Text To Columns

Comment: I meant the data is the same.

Comment: `Selection.Range("D3:D8")` may be incorrect  - perhaps you mean `ActiveSheet.Range("D3:D8")` ?   Would be useful to include a sample of the type of data you're working with.

Comment: In the first example you have `Chr(10)` (vbLf) as the delimiter under `OtherChar` but `Other` needs to be `True` for that to have any effect.  See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.texttocolumns#:~:text=True%20to%20have%20DataType%20be%20xlDelimited%20and%20to%20have%20the%20character%20specified%20by%20the%20OtherChar%20argument%20be%20a%20delimiter.%20The%20default%20value%20is%20False.

Comment: Hey, Thx for the response. I did make the changes, but still not working?

Comment: *`Selection.Range("D3:D8")` may be incorrect* as written by @TimWilliams.  If `Selection` was `D3:D8`, the range returned by that line would be `G5:G10`. I doubt this is what you want.  `Select` is a good thing to avoid. Use explicit references instead.  Search this forum for "How to avoid using select in VBA"

Comment: So how would the range return be G5:G10. ?

Comment: I realized when I run the code it doesn't work, but when I leave the workbook open and just run the Sub TextToCol() function it works lol

Comment: So it seems the ActiveSheet.Range("D3:D8) worked for me. I just need to figure out why it only works when I just run the TextToCol() once the data is there.

Comment: *how would the range return be G5:G10.*  See [MS Range.Range Property documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.range).

Comment: *why it only works when I just run the `TextToCol()` once the data is there.* Possibly `ActiveSheet` does not refer to `Worksheets("Sheet1")`.  If you search for the stackoverflow article I mentioned above in my very first comment, it includes advice and reasons for avoiding those kinds of references (eg `Active.Sheet`) also.